# Execute join statement with sqlite-net for WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone, sqlite-net

I'm using https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8 for my WP8 project.
I want to use joins event without automatical objects casting (like Query). Is there any method there to execute any query and then manually fetch result rows?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can execute any query and manually fetch rows.
this might help you out.
First you need to create a class that hold properties like -

```
 public class student
    {
    public int id{get;set;}
    public string StudentName{get;set;}
    public string ClassName{get;set;}
    }

After that create connection with database`.
You want to select id,StudentName from tableOne and ClassName from tableTwo


string query="SELECT tableOne.id,tableOne.StudentName.....your query with join";
 SQLiteCommand command = dbcon.CreateCommand(query);

var Data = command.ExecuteQuery<student>();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I though there is way without creating fetch object `student`.